# goemetrical progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

A credit society gives out a coompound interest of $4.5\text{%}$ per annum . Peter deposits shs.$300,000$ at the beginning if each year.How much money will ha have at the begging of the $\text{four}$ years if no withdrawal between this period is made during this period.

Answer (score 1):

The formula used to calculate the amount is:

$A = P\left(1+ \dfrac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}$. In this formula,

$A =$ amount,

$P =$ deposit,

$r = $ annual interest rate,

$n = $ the number of times the money is compounded per year,

$t = $ time in years.

The first deposit of $P_1 = 300,000$ will have: $A_1 = 300,000\times (1.045)^3$,
the second deposit of $P_2 = 300,000$ will have: $A_2 = 300,000\times (1.045)^2$,
the third deposit of $P_3 = 300,000$ will have: $A_3 = 300,000\times (1.045)^1$,
and the forth deposit of $P_4 = 300,000$ will have: $A_4 = 300,000$ in the account at this point.
Thus the total amount in the account at the beginning of the $4^{th}$ year is:

$S = A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4 = 1,283,457.34 \text{ shs}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically compunding so go like this.X is your starting value and C is your interest,then after one year we have $X  C$,after two years we have $(XC)C$ because after end of first year we have XC now we are just going one year further.

General formula comes out to be $XC^n$ where n is how many times you want to compound it,in your case 4.

Now next thing is that he makes a deposit every year,so at end of first year we have $XC + X$ at end of second year $(XC+X)C + X$...

General formula being $X +\sum_{i=2}^n XC^i$